# future cannot be sent between threads safely in async code

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I have an async function, that has a foor loop in it:

```
use std::time::Duration;

use async_trait::async_trait;
use scraper::{ Selector, Html };
use urlencoding::encode;

use crate::{
    currency::{ Currency, CurrencyConverter },
    comparer::{
        executor::{ BaseSiteInformation, Executor },
        model::{ Item, ItemPrice, Response, SiteResponse },
        error::Error,
    },
};

use super::common;

pub struct Site {
    pub info: BaseSiteInformation,
}

impl Site{
    async fn get_single_item(&self, url: String, currency: Currency) -> Item {
        let client = reqwest::Client
            ::builder()
            .cookie_store(true)
            .timeout(Duration::from_secs(20))
            .build()
            .unwrap();

        let inital_response = client
            .get(url)
            .header(
                "User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            )
            .header("Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform", "\"Windows\"")
            .header("Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile", "?0")
            .header(
                "Sec-Ch-Ua",
                "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"119\", \"Chromium\";v=\"119\", \"Not?A_Brand\";v=\"24"
            )
            .send().await
            .unwrap();

        let inital_response = Html::parse_document(&inital_response.text().await.unwrap());

        let selector = Selector::parse("div#list").unwrap();

        let item_list = inital_response.select(&selector);

        let mut extracted_prices: Vec<String> = vec![];

        let price_selector = Selector::parse("span").unwrap();

        let prices = item_list.last().unwrap().select(&price_selector);

        for price in prices {
            if price.attr("divprop").is_some() {
                let price = price.attr("content").unwrap().to_string();

                let value = CurrencyConverter::convert(
                    price.parse::<f64>().unwrap(),
                    currency,
                    self.info.currency
                );

                extracted_prices.push(value.to_string());
            }
        }

        let link_selector = Selector::parse("a.overlay").unwrap();

        let item_list = inital_response.select(&selector);

        let links = item_list.last().unwrap().select(&link_selector);

        let mut collected_links = vec![];

        for link in links {
            if link.attr("href").is_some() {
                let link = link.attr("href").unwrap().to_string();

                let actual_url = common::get_resolved_url(link, &client).await;

                collected_links.push(actual_url);
            }
        }

        let name_selector = Selector::parse("div.top h1.visible-xs").unwrap();

        let name = inital_response
            .select(&name_selector)
            .last()
            .unwrap()
            .inner_html()
            .to_string()
            .trim()
            .to_string();

        let mut item_prices = vec![];

        let mut i = 0;

        while i < collected_links.len() {
            item_prices.push(ItemPrice {
                link: collected_links.get(i).unwrap().to_string(),
                price: extracted_prices.get(i).unwrap().to_string(),
            });
            i += 1;
        }

        Item { item: name, prices: item_prices }
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl Executor for Site {
    async fn collect(&self, prompt: String, currency: Currency) -> Result<Response, Error> {
        let client = reqwest::Client::builder().timeout(Duration::from_secs(20)).build().unwrap();

        let inital_response = client
            .get(self.info.base_url.clone().replace("{PROMPT}", &encode(&prompt)))
            .header(
                "User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            )
            .header("Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform", "\"Windows\"")
            .header("Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile", "?0")
            .header(
                "Sec-Ch-Ua",
                "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"119\", \"Chromium\";v=\"119\", \"Not?A_Brand\";v=\"24"
            )
            .send().await?;

        let inital_response = inital_response.text().await?;

        let inital_response = serde_json::from_str::<SiteResponse>(&inital_response)?;

        let initial_items = Html::parse_document(&inital_response.dom);

        let selector = Selector::parse("ul.products li a").unwrap();

        let initial_items = initial_items.select(&selector);

        let mut items = vec![];

        for item in initial_items {
            let local_item = item.clone();

            let item_link = local_item.attr("href").unwrap().to_string();

            let collected = self.get_single_item(item_link.clone(), currency).await;

            items.push(collected);
        }

        Ok(Response { items })
    }
}
```

I am awaiting `get_single_item`, if I do that I get red squigly lines for all the whole function:

```
future cannot be sent between threads safely
within `ego_tree::Node<Node>`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `Cell<NonZeroUsize>`
if you want to do aliasing and mutation between multiple threads, use `std::sync::RwLock`
required for the cast from `Pin<Box<{async block@src\carer\executor.rs:138:92: 178:6}>>` to `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = Result<model::Response, comparer::error::Error>> + std::marker::Send>>`
```

Now, if I modify the await to `executor::block_on`, my code compiles. I am using tokio for my runtime btw.

I dont understand the difference why this works, and how can I make my code work even with the await.

Comment: Please add definitions for all missing items `initial_items`, the types of your variables, etc, so that this post includes a [mre] we can work with.

Comment: Updated the question with the code from the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `executor::block_on` you are blocking the current thread until the future is complete.

It is difficult to add a solid answer, but based on your current code, I could says the different is caused because the `Future` is not a `Send`.

If you want to keep the asynchronous, you need to implement the function `get_single_item` and it has to return a Future that is marked as Send.

```
async fn get_single_item(..., currency: Currency) -> Result<..., ...>
{
   //TODO: ADD YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: I stepped away from my machine, but regarding the future that is marked as send, you mean the result type struct has to implement the send trust?

Comment: Updated the original post with source